# Missing Token for Amazon SimpleNotificationService Request Amazon AWS SDK

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I am trying to use the .NET SDK (2.3.35.0) and create an endpoint (APNS subscription).  I already have an application defined in AWS and have an Application arn.  I have one APNS token (endpoint) already stored and through the console I have been able to send push notifications to that device.

What I am having a hard time with is sending a createPlatformEndpoint to Amazon's SNS system.  I am getting this error:

```
"Message": "An error has occurred.",
  "ExceptionMessage": "Request is missing Authentication Token",
  "ExceptionType": "Amazon.SimpleNotificationService.AmazonSimpleNotificationServiceException"
```

This is my method for sending the request:

```
public void addAPNSSubscription(string platformAppARN, string deviceToken)
{
  using (var client = new AmazonSimpleNotificationServiceClient(_snsAccessKey, _snsSecretAccessKey, _snsClientConfig))
  {
    var endpointRequest = new CreatePlatformEndpointRequest { PlatformApplicationArn = platformAppARN, Token = deviceToken };
    endpointRequest.CustomUserData = "Testing from .NET";

   var result = client.CreatePlatformEndpoint(endpointRequest);
  }
}
```

I am sure the missing Authentication Token is an OAuth token, I just don't know how to get that through the .NET SDK.  Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am stupid.  I was using an existing class, and assumed the config properties were being read properly.  They weren't.  When I fixed that issue, the request went off without a problem.